# iOS Core Data images not actually being deleted

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift3

I have an app that is saving images from camera to Core Data using a table view. When I swipe to delete the everything looks fine. After loading images into the app I see the app size increase in the devices settings for Manage Storage, as it should increase. But when I swipe to delete, the app size never decreases, even if I delete them all.  Has anyone had a similar experience.

Comment: check you are really deleting and save the context of core data . If you are not doing so it will not be deleted

Comment: @Vinodh This is what I'm putting in my delete function  context.delete(objects_here)             appDelegate.saveContext()

Answer (score 0):

It might have happened that you would be removing the entry from `CoreData` but not removing the actual resource from the document directory.

You can user `removeItem` method of File Manager to remove the file from the application document directory and then check if there is any changes in size,.

Comment: After checking , Core Data isn't saving the images or anything in dodcuments directory.

Comment: then it might happen you might be writing image. Can you share your code?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) { var objs = controller.fetchedObjects let object = (objs?[indexPath.row]) // print(object!) DatabaseController.getContext().delete(object!) DatabaseController.saveContext() } tableView.reloadData() } Is there suppose to be a better way to post code here

Comment: @user2103669 You can edit your question and put the code over there. But in this you are only deleting the object from coredata I guess.